# How to communicate information between a python script and an iPhone app

Tags: python, xcode, raspberry-pi

I have a python script running on a Raspberry Pi, and this script gathers real-time information about the Raspberry Pi, storing the information into variables. I would like to use an iPhone app that I am creating to retrieve this information and display it on screen each time a button is pressed.

I have found solutions online involving REST APIs as well as software like ZeroMQ; however, I am very unfamiliar with these types of things and am unsure which approach to use. What is the simplest approach that you would suggest, and how might I go about implementing it?

Comment: i would consider using sockets, an easy to follow article at https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: How are the iPhone and Raspberry Pi physically connected? Are they on the same network? Are you enabling your WiFi Hotspot on the iPhone and connecting the Pi to that? Or do you want to use Bluetooth? Or do you want to push to some server somewhere on the Internet from the Pi and pull from that server on the iPhone? Do you have a server?

Comment: The goal is to create a system where the connection doesn't matter since the system is for a client(s). So I'd like to do what you said last – push to some server on the Internet from the Pi or from the iPhone and then pull from the other device. And no, I don't have a server. Honestly, I don't have experience with this and would like to implement as simple a solution as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few ways I thought of doing it:

1. Use [SMPT email protocol to send yourself an email](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email/) which you can access on your iphone.
2. Pay for an SMS service to send [SMS messages to your iphone.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-python)
3. Push to https://jsonstorage.net/ on your Rasberry Pi, then access the storage bin on your iphone.
4. If it's running Windows or Linux. You can download [Dropbox Desktop](https://www.dropbox.com/install). This will give you a folder that is automatically updated on changes which you can check from anywhere.

#### Further details:

3. How to update a json bin with python

```
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",'dataType': "json"}
data = json.dumps(json_data_you_want_to_upload)
url = https://jsonstorage.net/api/items/your-bin-id
resp = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data)
if resp.status_code == 200 or 201:
    print(f'Data successfull uploaded: {resp.json()})')
else:
    print(f'Error! Could not upload to the database: {resp.json()}')
```